# Why does getEnum return null when the enum object exists?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, enums, apache-commons

I'm looking at a class similar to the one below. I changed the class name and variable names to avoid putting the actual company names on here (sorry).

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.enums.Enum;

public class Animal extends Enum {

    public static final Animal DOG = new Animal("Dog");
    public static final Animal CAT = new Animal("Cat");

    private Animal(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public static Animal getAnimal(String code) {
        return (Animal) getEnum(Animal.class, code);
    }
}
```

When getAnimal is passed "Dog" as a parameter it returns an Animal. However, when passed "Cat" as a parameter, it returns null. Why might something like this happen?

Comment: Why aren't you just using the built in Enum support? public enum Animal...

Comment: To explain Ryan Amos comment: unless you're still developing for Java 1.4 (which is obsolete for a looooong time: we're at Java 7 now), you shouldn't use Apache lang enums anymore. Java has built-in support for enums since Java 5.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am developing for Java 1.4...big company, slow to change. I don't have control over this right now. I didn't write this class, just trying to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern Java, you'd write:

```
enum Animal {
    Dog, Cat;
}
```

and use

```
Animal.valueOf(name)
```

to get the enum value from its name. (Enum types have been added in Java 5, which was released more than 7 years ago.)

If you are still stuck on a Java version that doesn't support enums, one approach would be to debug `org.apache.commons.lang.enums.Enum.getValue`. The implementation is hardly going to be rocket science ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to extend `ValuedEnum` instead of `Enum` (see the examples in the [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/enum/ValuedEnum.html))